# "Expression is not assignable" error with add operator?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two similar statements but one of them is giving me an error that "Expression is not assignable".
Following is giving the error.

```
self.selectedLine.begin.x += translation.x;
```

and this one works fine.

```
CGPoint start = self.selectedLine.begin;
start.x += translation.x;
```

Is this something to do with property's getter and setter?

Here `selectedLine` is a object of class SSSLine which represent a line. SSSLine class has two properties :

```
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint begin;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a property is a struct, you cannot assign to a member of the struct; you must assign the entire struct. In this case, if `begin` is a `CGPoint`:

```
CGPoint start = self.selectedLine.begin;
start.x += translation.x;
self.selectedLine.begin = start;
```

Comment: Thanks Justin for the answer.